# GEF can't find python modules in virtualenv

Tags: python, python3, gdb

I wanted to try out [GEF](https://github.com/hugsy/gef) but I am having some issues with `missing commands`. The tools says it's because of missing python packages, but I just installed them in a clean virtualenv to try.

I am attaching a screenshot that explains the situation.
[image]

Does anyone know how to make GEF recognize the installed packages?